# Let $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f(f(x)) + f(x) + x = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Find all $f(x)$.

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

Let $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f(f(x)) + f(x) + x = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Find all $f(x)$.

---

I already proved that $f(x)$ is injective. But I didn’t know how to use the fact that $f$ is continuous. Can anyone give a hint or a solution to this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Better phrasing is “Find all continuous $f:\mathbb{R}\to\nathbb{R}$ such that...”. Your wording suggests $f is fixed already.

Comment: Thank you. I’m sorry. I am not good at typing.